# How do you pass the value of one query in to another query MySQL without using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Just got a quick question, this is a simple thing to do via PHP but I'm pretty sure there has to be a way to do it via MySQL.

I've got a table with the columns id, element_id, video_link, views among a few others.

What I want to do select one out of the top 5 most viewed videos at random.

E.g

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE "In human terms order by views descending and then select 1 of the top 5 at random"
```

It's really simple to do via PHP and I will use that if there isn't a way to do it via MySQL but it would be nice to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM `tablename`
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 5
) AS inner_table
ORDER BY RAND( )
```

Comment: Great! That did just the job, thanks a lot, that's going to be really helpful for future queries. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (  SELECT * FROM table_name 
      WHERE name  = 'aas' 
     ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5 
  )
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM table WHERE <order by something> LIMIT 0,5) 
ORDER BY 
   RAND() 
LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: I just gave that a go, and I was given this error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias, here is my code 

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tvmanager ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

Comment: You must use alias for inner query.. look at the below answer

Comment: All it needed was the added AS inner_table before the final ORDER BY, thanks for the help!